# Gnome Display Manager (gdm) runlevel 5 not working, black screen on console

Tags: rhel, nvidia, console, graphics, gdm

I have a supermicro server that has worked fine for however long, and monthly do `yum update` on it and it is currently at RHEL 7.9 `3.10.0-1160.15.2.el7.x86_64`.  It is one Nvidia K620 graphics card having one white DVI output port, in addition to the mainboard blue vga port.

Using a 24" 1920x1200 monitor off the mainboard blue VGA port, everything linux in basic black & white text displays on it up until runlevel 5, and in runlevel 3 I get a text based login screen on VGA monitor.  When going to runlevel 5 (i.e. graphical.target) the vga mode on the monitor goes blank and then I switch the monitor to DVI mode and then get the gnome graphical login display coming from the k620 graphics card.  This is how it has worked and I was happy with it.

After updating to `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-460.32.03.run` I am stuck with only the text login (runlevel 3) on VGA monitor.  When I try to go to graphical.target and put the monitor to DVI I get a black screen If I remote in over the network via VNC the gnome desktop and everything still works.

Additionally, a similar server having only a blue mainboard VGA but having an Nvidia P100 gpgu (no graphics output) worked where the runlevel 5 graphical console displayed to the VGA console monitor.  But now after an nvidia [cuda] update I no longer have a graphical console there either and am stuck with basic text console.

I believe this to be a RHEL linux and/or gnome display manager problem, and not necessarily nvidia; I am looking for insight as to what is happening and how to regain my runlevel 5 graphical login console.  *All I ever knew of was `nvidia-xconfig` and that worked on the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`  and prior to my problems with everything working just fine in RHEL 7.9 there actually was no `xorg.conf` file present; so I know I am about completely ignorant as to how graphics works now in rhel 7.9.  please help.  How does one fix gdm, what if anything related to gdm can I try?*

Comment: Please post the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to e.g. pastebin.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this stated in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/421683

The redhat solution only mentioned `mesa-libGL`
For reference this is what I did that was successful:

- unblacklist nouveau in /etc/default/grub followed by grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
- `rpm -ev --nodeps     mesa-libGLES mesa-libGLU mesa-libGL-devel mesa-dri-drivers mesa-libEGL-devel mesa-libEGL mesa-libxatracker mesa-libgbm mesa-libGLU-devel mesa-filesystem mesa-libOSMesa mesa-khr-devel mesa-libglapi mesa-libGLw mesa-libGL`
- `yum install  mesa* xorg-x11-drv-nouveau`
- `dracut -vf`
- `yum history sync` to remove yum altered outside warning.
- if using dkms do `dkms status` and be sure it responds empty regarding nvidia.
- reboot
- console graphics restored, as had been prior to installing nvidia or cuda.